# Iteratively find minimum values in sub-lists

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I need to find and store in a new list the minimum values in each sub-list of a main list. This is what I have so far:

```
# Main list.
list_a = [[0.2,0.4,0.6,1.1], [1.2,0.1,0.7,0.9], [0.3,0.5,0.9,0.7], [0.5,0.2,0.6,0.3]]

# List that stores all the minimum values.
list_b = []

# Iterate through all sub-lists in main list.
for sub_list in list_a:
    # Identify minimum value in sub-list.
    min_val = np.argmin(sub_list)
    # Store this minimum value in list_b.
    list_b.append(sub_list[min_val])
```

This way, `list_b` will look like:

```
print list_b
[0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2]
```

Is there a more efficient/pythonic way to do this?

---

### Answers

I checked the answers given by **1_CR**, **Haidro** and **DSM**. Compared to my initial proposal for this issue, they ranked as following according to `time.time()`:

- 0.00774312019348, my code
- 0.0201649665833, 1_CR
- 0.0234789848328, Haidro
- 0.0014910697937, DSM

Compared to my original approach, DSM's is the fastest solution by ~5x, with the other two taking ~28x longer. All are great solutions but because of the performance, I'll mark DSM's as the accepted answer. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is tagged `numpy`, if your `list_a` has a rectangular shape, you could use `numpy` functions instead.

For example:

```
>>> np.min(list_a, axis=1)
array([ 0.2,  0.1,  0.3,  0.2])
```

or, to avoid repeated conversions, make it an `array`:

```
>>> b = np.array(list_a)
>>> b.min(axis=1)
array([ 0.2,  0.1,  0.3,  0.2])
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a list comprehension and the `min` function

```
[min(x) for x in list_a]
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`min()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min):

```
list_b = map(min, list_a)
```